# ParseJSON using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am unable to extract `msg` from the JSON response. `@returnCode` works fine and I am passing it to SSJS, but then I cannot get the `msg` value.

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var jsonresponse = Variable.GetValue("@response");
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonresponse.msg);
Write("<br>message: " + msg);
</script>
```

Here's my json for reference:

> {"msg":"success","date":"2019-08-12","explanation":"xxxxxxx"}

Any idea what is wrong with above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have any variable named *msg*.
Try this:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var jsonresponse = Variable.GetValue("@response");
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonresponse);
Write("<br>message: " + json.msg);
</script>
```

Comment: oh wow, that was simple - thanks!!