# BuildRowSetFromXML with "attribute-id" with multiple data points?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml, xmlparsing

I'm being asked to display some data coming through our XML feed in our emails. The data is coming through as a custom-attribute but appears as multiple data points that need to be displayed separately in the email. I know how to reference a custom attribute as explained here. [How to use BuildRowSetFromXML with an "attribute-id" in SFMC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253170/how-to-use-buildrowsetfromxml-with-an-attribute-id-in-sfmc) but what I need can't find is how to reference "ID", "name", "address", and "url" separately.

XML reference

```xml
<custom-attribute attribute-id="dataexample">
[{"ID":"123","name":"Nameexample","address":"1234 1st StMineolaNY11501-1521(111)111-1111","url":"urlexample"}]
</custom-attribute>
```

My code

```
set @dataexample = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="dataexample"]',0),1), 'Value')
```

Comment: This is JSON and not XML. I will recommend using SSJS for this, like in this [example.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273260/parsejson-using-ssjs)

Answer (score 1):

In your XML parsing, I'd definitely check for a match first -- with a [rowcount](https://ampscript.guide/rowcount).

Once you have the value, switch to SSJS to parse the JSON.

In the SSJS block, retrieve the value of the AMPscript var and parse it with the [parseJSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.html) function.  You'll want a try/catch block around that so you can explicitly handle any malformed JSON.

Upon a successful parse, you can set an AMPscript variable for it.  Then you can reference the AMPscript variable in-line (like at the very end).

```html
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">

set @dataexample = ""

if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="dataexample"]')) > 0 then
    set @dataexample = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@XML, '/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="dataexample"]',0),1), 'Value')
endif

</script>
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
 
 Platform.Load("Core","1");

 // get the value of the AMPscript var
 var dataexample = Variable.GetValue("@dataexample")
   
 try {

  // attempt to parse the JSON  
  var dataexampleJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(dataexample);

  // set value of name property, use jsonpathfinder.com to validate JSON reference
  var name = dataexample[0].name;

  // set an AMPscript variable for the results
  Variable.SetValue("@name",name); 


 } catch (e) {

    // might want to raiseError here if the payload values are critical 
    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e))
 }

</script>

Name: %%=v(@name)=%%
```

I didn't include in my answer, but you'll probably want to check to make sure `dataexample` has a value in the SSJS block before the try/catch.