# XML attribute-id line items not populating with AMPscript and JSON parse

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

Attempting to land `attribute-id` (price) data on "price" with XML below using ampscript and JAVA which is not showing a result for `%%=v(@price)=%%` in HTML body.

XML

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="shippingAdultSignatureFees">{"feeId":1,"name","actualFeeCharge":0,"addPriceToShippingCost":false,"price":2}</custom-attribute>
```

current script in email:

```
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">

set @shippingAdultSignatureFees = ""

SET @orderxml = AttributeValue("OrderAsXML") if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@orderxml, '/order/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="shippingAdultSignatureFees"]')) > 0 then set @shippingAdultSignatureFees = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@orderxml, '/order/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="shippingAdultSignatureFees"]',0),1), 'Value') endif 
</script><script runat="server" language="javascript">
 
 Platform.Load("Core","1");

 // get the value of the AMPscript var
 var shippingAdultSignatureFees = Variable.GetValue("@shippingAdultSignatureFees")
   
 try {

  // attempt to parse the JSON  
  var shippingAdultSignatureFeesJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(shippingAdultSignatureFees);

  // set value of name property
  var price = shippingAdultSignatureFees[0].price;

  // set an AMPscript variable
  Variable.SetValue("@price",price); 


 } catch (e) {

    // might want to raiseError here if the payload values are critical 
    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e))
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Parsing and retrieving these attribute values from XML has been discussed a few times, e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/370690/5202

Comment: I can get the attribue-id value but not the "price" using this xml code. <custom-attribute attribute-id="shippingAdultSignatureFees">{"feeId":1,"name","actualFeeCharge":0,"addPriceToShippingCost":false,"price":2}</custom-attribute>

Comment: The JSON in that tag pair is invalid and not parsable in it's current state. The `name` has no value.  You can verify it by copy-pasting the JSON in a site like https://jsonpathfinder.com.  It'd need to be something like this to work: `{"feeId":1,"name":"whee!","actualFeeCharge":0,"addPriceToShippingCost":false,"price":2}`

Comment: Thank you Adam. It appears values for all the fields must exist before hitting the price field before calling out the desired price value. Is there any code to force and skip non-values in the xml?

Comment: It'd be tricky to fix invalid JSON with AMPscript/SSJS.  It should be fixed at the source, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your input Adam. Much appreciated!